# Is there any difference between meanings of "fortress" and "stronghold"?

Tags: word-choice

Is *fortress* higher/larger/moderner than *stronghold*?  For example in history?

I found there is a same meaning of the two words.

Here in this [game](http://classic.battle.net/war3/orc/buildings.shtml), *fortress* seems to be higher than *stronghold* in hierarchy.

Comment: [Differences between “fortification nouns”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123334/differences-between-fortification-nouns)

Answer (score 2):

It seems *fortress* and *stronghold* are synonyms, basically meaning ***a fortified place***. Merriam Webster defines both [*stronghold*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stronghold) and [*fortress*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortress) and in *fortress*'s definition *stronghold* is directly mentioned. So it seems they are same.

However, it seems *stronghold* never surpassed *fortress* in terms of popularity of usage:

[image]

**EDIT-** Thanks to @snailboat for pointing out a significant usage of *stronghold* where *stronghold* holds a metaphorical sense that *fortress* does not. I am directly including the passage she mentioned from The New York Times.

> According to recent census data, Mexicans, Dominicans and Ecuadoreans now make up a huge share of the foreign-born population. The area was once a Polish ***stronghold*** — hence the word “eagle” in many business names, an allusion to Poland’s coat of arms, said Jeff Richman, the Green-Wood Cemetery historian and a font of local lore.

Here "***stronghold***" does not only mean literally a defensive position or fort, but it means that Polish has been dominating the place for a long time due to their presence in a large number in that area and now other communities are taking bites out of Polish's dominance by populating the place.